# SSH from Windows to Linux with key denied

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

I used ssh-keygen on Linux and id_rsa.pub is in .ssh/authorized-keys in my Windows home. I disabled the inhertinace like some comments say.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I used `ssh-keygen` on Linux and `id_rsa.pub` is in `.ssh/authorized-keys` in my Windows home." – This looks like a setup to `ssh` from Linux to Windows. The title says "Windows to Linux". Please review. The private key of the client should be known only to the client, the public key of the client should be known (in `authorized_keys`) to the server. BTW, I don't know solutions specific to Windows, but for OpenSSH the relevant file is `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (with an underscore, not with a hyphen).

Comment: We need the OpenSSH server configuration file. We also need a screenshot of the permissions of the key file. The only user who should have access to the file is the user who will be using it.

Comment: the main issue us that the public key needs to be in .ssh/authorized_keys on the server (in your vague description that would be in Linux), not the client (Windows) - and the private key needs to be in `.ssh/id_rsa` in Windows

Comment: It's Windows to Linux. I used ssh-keygen on Linux because I'm used to it and copied the pubkey to Windows, thinking I could easily just ssh into Linux from Powershell since some Unix commands seem to work. Do you want the screenshot from Windows? The server file (on Linux) is basically unchanged, just enabling pubkey authentication. Or is keygen supposed to be run on the client? I don't remember.